# How can I use app _ process to execute dex call the removeaccountexpedictly method of the IAccountManager class

Tags: android

The problem I have is, When I finish writing java code to generate dex and execute it on an Android device using the app _ process command, I encountered an anomaly. When I use the root call, it returns the following exception

```java
java.lang.SecurityException: uid 0 cannot remove accounts of type: org.telegram.messenger
```

When I switched to the system user and tried to run again, a new exception occurred. The log is as follows

```
7958-7958  app_process             pid-7958                             A  runtime.cc:675]   native: #02 pc 000000000062f670  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+72) (BuildId: 712666bec271d835f4eb1f6b0d41318a)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #03 pc 000000000062f2d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+456) (BuildId: 712666bec271d835f4eb1f6b0d41318a)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #04 pc 00000000006199cc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1272) (BuildId: 712666bec271d835f4eb1f6b0d41318a)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #05 pc 0000000000017114  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+84) (BuildId: ef369bfbad96b532c6d8e0b144a68b96)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #06 pc 0000000000016648  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+356) (BuildId: ef369bfbad96b532c6d8e0b144a68b96)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #07 pc 0000000000667b2c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::AssertNoPendingException() const+1572) (BuildId: 712666bec271d835f4eb1f6b0d41318a)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #08 pc 00000000002a4424  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::FindClass(art::Thread*, char const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+68) (BuildId: 712666bec271d835f4eb1f6b0d41318a)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #09 pc 0000000000463420  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::FindClass(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+1016) (BuildId: 712666bec271d835f4eb1f6b0d41318a)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #10 pc 00000000000c5278  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::register_android_util_SeempLog(_JNIEnv*)+36) (BuildId: ca67843cc66193e6f4f2255f9e6f4b55)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #11 pc 00000000000cd9b4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::startReg(_JNIEnv*)+68) (BuildId: ca67843cc66193e6f4f2255f9e6f4b55)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #12 pc 00000000000cd670  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+512) (BuildId: ca67843cc66193e6f4f2255f9e6f4b55)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #13 pc 0000000000002610  /system/bin/app_process64 (main+1464) (BuildId: 6363373b68588b10c93602a28a32bb57)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   native: #14 pc 000000000008580c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+100) (BuildId: 607a29162b319a50c57abd2b2141d335)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675]   (no managed stack frames)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675] Pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ma.NotificationPolicy.Main

                                                                            runtime.cc:675] (Throwable with empty stack trace)

                                                                            runtime.cc:675] 

 7958-7958  app_process             pid-7958                             A  runtime.cc:683] No pending exception expected: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ma.NotificationPolicy.Main

                                                                            runtime.cc:683] (Throwable with empty stack trace)

                                                                            runtime.cc:683] 

 7999-7999  DEBUG                   pid-7999                             A  Cmdline: app_process / ma.NotificationPolicy.Main a

 7999-7999  DEBUG                   pid-7999                             A  Abort message: 'No pending exception expected: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ma.NotificationPolicy.Main

                                                                            (Throwable with empty stack trace)'
```

the main code

```java
    private static IBinder getSystemService(String name){
        try {
            @SuppressLint({"PrivateApi", "DiscouragedPrivateApi"})
            Method getServiceMethod = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getDeclaredMethod("getService", String.class);
            getServiceMethod.setAccessible(true);
            return (IBinder) getServiceMethod.invoke(null, name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

 private static Account[] getAccountsAsUser(){

        try {
            @SuppressLint({"PrivateApi"})
            Class<?> cStub =  Class.forName("android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub");
            Method asInterface = cStub.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Object mObjManager = asInterface.invoke(null, getSystemService("account"));
            return (Account[]) mObjManager.getClass()
                    .getMethod("getAccountsAsUser", String.class, int.class, String.class)
                    .invoke(mObjManager,null, 0, "com.android.settings");
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

 private static boolean removeAccountExplicitly(Account account){

        try {
            @SuppressLint({"PrivateApi"})
            Class<?> cStub =  Class.forName("android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub");
            Method asInterface = cStub.getMethod("asInterface", IBinder.class);
            Object mObjManager = asInterface.invoke(null, getSystemService("account"));
            Method method = mObjManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("removeAccountExplicitly", Account.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            return (boolean) method.invoke(mObjManager,account);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I tried to switch the user to system and execute it like this

```
su system -c "export CLASSPATH = /data/local/tmp/classes.dex; app_process / ma.Notification Policy.Main",
```

I expected it to remove the account object I specified, but it threw me an classnotfound exception

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I solved the problem, Ignoring the basic permission issues, I moved the dex file from / sdcard to the / data / local / tmp directory, And give it 644 permissions using the chmod command. I can now use uid: system to execute the removeAccountExplicitly method. I'm still told that system users can't delete accounts directly, But when I called another method called removeAccountAsUser, it successfully deleted all the accounts I specified